# Simplifying tableview code with function calling custom tableview cell

Tags: swift, function, uitableview, swift3, tableview

Looking to simplify my code by using a function inside my tableview function. I think it's possible, but I can't figure out how to even begin. I tried creating a function to perform the actions I want, but I can't figure out how to call the custom cell variables in my function.

Here is the code I want to simplify:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        // PART 1
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell1", for: indexPath) as! PaydayDetailCellA1
        let (jobDescription, day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7, _) = tempPaydayDailyJobs[indexPath.row]

        cell.tallyView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.tallyView.bounds.height / 6.4
        cell.tallyView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.tallyView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        cell.tallyView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

        cell.jobDesc.text = jobDescription

        cell.dayColor1.text = day1
        switch day1 {
        case "1":
            cell.dayColor1.text = ""
            cell.dayColor1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
        case "X":
            cell.dayColor1.text = ""
            cell.dayColor1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        case "E":
            cell.dayColor1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        default:
            cell.dayColor1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
            cell.dayColor1.textColor = UIColor.white
        }

        cell.dayColor2.text = day2
        switch day2 {
        case "1":
            cell.dayColor2.text = ""
            cell.dayColor2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
        case "X":
            cell.dayColor2.text = ""
            cell.dayColor2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        case "E":
            cell.dayColor2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        default:
            cell.dayColor2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
            cell.dayColor2.textColor = UIColor.white
        }

        cell.dayColor3.text = day3
        switch day3 {
        case "1":
            cell.dayColor3.text = ""
            cell.dayColor3.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
        case "X":
            cell.dayColor3.text = ""
            cell.dayColor3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        case "E":
            cell.dayColor3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        default:
            cell.dayColor3.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
            cell.dayColor3.textColor = UIColor.white
        }

        cell.dayColor4.text = day4
        switch day4 {
        case "1":
            cell.dayColor4.text = ""
            cell.dayColor4.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
        case "X":
            cell.dayColor4.text = ""
            cell.dayColor4.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        case "E":
            cell.dayColor4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        default:
            cell.dayColor4.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
            cell.dayColor4.textColor = UIColor.white
        }

        cell.dayColor5.text = day5
        switch day5 {
        case "1":
            cell.dayColor5.text = ""
            cell.dayColor5.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
        case "X":
            cell.dayColor5.text = ""
            cell.dayColor5.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        case "E":
            cell.dayColor5.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        default:
            cell.dayColor5.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
            cell.dayColor5.textColor = UIColor.white
        }

        cell.dayColor6.text = day6
        switch day6 {
        case "1":
            cell.dayColor6.text = ""
            cell.dayColor6.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
        case "X":
            cell.dayColor6.text = ""
            cell.dayColor6.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        case "E":
            cell.dayColor6.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        default:
            cell.dayColor6.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
            cell.dayColor6.textColor = UIColor.white
        }

        cell.dayColor7.text = day7
        switch day7 {
        case "1":
            cell.dayColor7.text = ""
            cell.dayColor7.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
        case "X":
            cell.dayColor7.text = ""
            cell.dayColor7.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        case "E":
            cell.dayColor7.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        default:
            cell.dayColor7.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 198/255, blue: 63/255, alpha: 1)
            cell.dayColor7.textColor = UIColor.white
        }

        return cell

    } else {
        // PART 2
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell2", for: indexPath) as! PaydayDetailCellA2
        let (_, pointAmount) = tempDailyChoresSummary[indexPath.row]

        cell2.dailyChoresNumber.text = "\(pointAmount)"
        cell2.jobConsistencyBonusNumber.text = "\(pointAmount)"
        cell2.previousUnpaidAmountsNumber.text = "\(pointAmount)"
        cell2.dailyChoresSubtotalNumber.text = "\(pointAmount)"

        return cell2
    }
}
```

I have a block of labels inside a custom tableview cell. I want the background color of the labels to change color depending on the data in an exterior array. I've attached a picture of what it looks like (if that helps). [Here is the picture of the tableview with colored labels.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhELj.png)

Or is there a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach can reduce the code in the table function. Bear in mind, this is a concept. 
You can break out some of the repetitive property settings by creating an extension to UITableViewCell.

First create a protocol

```
protocol Settable {
    func setData(val: Int)
}
```

Then make an extension

```
extension Settable {
    func setData(jobDescription: String, jobSubtotal: String, cornerRadius: Float, maskToBounds: Bool, borderColor: CGColor, borderWidth: Float) {
        self.tallyView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.tallyView.layer.masksToBounds = maskToBounds
        self.tallyView.layer.borderColor = borderColor
        self.tallyView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.jobDesc.text = jobDescription
        self.jobSubtotal.text = jobSubtotal
    }
}
```

Then extend your UITableViewCell

```
class PaydayNewCellA1 : UITableViewCell, Settable {

}
class PaydayNewCellB1 : UITableViewCell, Settable {

}
class PaydayNewCellC1 : UITableViewCell, Settable {

}
```

Then you can do the following in your function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell1", for: indexPath) as! PaydayNewCellA1
            // Now use the function
            cell.setData(jobDescription: "daily job \(indexPath.row + 1)", jobSubtotal: "50", cornerRadius: cell.tallyView.bounds.height / 6.4, maskToBounds: true, borderColor: UIColor.lightGray.cgColor, borderWidth: 0.5)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell2", for: indexPath) as! PaydayNewCellA2
            return cell
        }
    } else if (tableView == tableView2) {

     // rest of code etc

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as a previous user noticed, I had posted the wrong code, and so your answer, albeit excellent, doesn't solve my problem. Please see the updated code. (I may have posted it about the same time you were posting your answer, and so you never saw the updated code).